# Ionic3 how to play audio file?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, audio, ionic3

I am trying to make a audio player for Ionic3.
First, I used tag in html. It works on IOS but not work in Android.
Second, I tried @ionic-native/media. But it should record first and can play.
I am wondering to how to implement audio player.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use [**Ionic-audio**](http://arielfaur.github.io/ionic-audio/2.0/index.html) plugin for that.

Here is the [**Demo**](http://arielfaur.github.io/ionic-audio-example/)

```
npm install ionic-audio --save
```

> An audio player plugin for Ionic that works out of the box in the
>   browser and device using an underlying audio provider depending on the
>   environment. When running inside the browser the plugin will default
>   to a Web Audio provider, whereas on a device it will switch to Cordova
>   Media if cordova-plugin-media is available, otherwise falls back to
>   web audio.

[**Git Repo**](https://github.com/arielfaur/ionic-audio/tree/2.0)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try it, now.

Comment: Yep, Ok sure.Good Luck :)